# nHibernate QueryOver: Filter length of main element and the length of sub elements

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have two entities: `Pakage` and `Pole`. The `Pakage` contains multiple `Poles` which are liked in pakage as reverse set.

I have a GUI which shows all `Pakages` if no restrictions are set on the GUI. One of the possible restrictions is to define a minimum length of the `Pakage`. This worked great. But no I am also supposed to show (and consider) the length of `Poles` in a `Pakages`. So if the user sets a minimum length of 2.0m I must show all `Pakages` which have a length >= 2.0m and also all `Pakages` which contain a `Pole` with a length >= 2.0m.

```
public class Pakage : IComparable
{
    public virtual decimal Length { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Pole> Poles { get; set; } = new HashSet<Pole>();
    /* other stuff */
}

public class Pakage : IComparable
{
    public virtual decimal Length { get; set; }
    /* other stuff */
}
```

nHibernate Mapping in `Pakage`

```
<set name="Poles" table="pole" inverse="true">
  <key column="pakageid" foreign-key="FK_pole_pakage" />
  <one-to-many class="Pole" />
</set>
```

Now I want to query all pakages and list them in a grid view. To filter the pakages I have several numerical up and down elements. First I tried this:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Pakage>();

if (seLengthFrom.EditValue != null)
{
    query.Where(pakage => pakage.Length >= seLengthFrom.Value || pakage.Poles.Count(p => p.Length >= seLengthFrom.Value) > 0);
}
```

This gave me an error: `'variable 'pakage' of type 'App.Pakage' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined`

So I changed it to the following, which lead to longer load times since I am loading a lot more elements:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Pakage>();
var poleJoin = query.Left.JoinQueryOver(pakage => pakage.Pole);

if (seLengthFrom.EditValue != null)
{
    query.Where(
        Restrictions.Disjunction()
        .Add(Restrictions.Where<)Pakage>(x => x.Length >= seLengthFrom.Value))
        .Add(Restrictions.Where<Pole>(z => z.Length >= seLengthFrom.Value))
    );

}

IList<Pakage> pakageList = query.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity).List();
```

This second approach did not work, since the SQL generated from nHibernate did something like this:

```
WHERE           (
                                this_.length >= @p0
                OR              this_.length >= @p1);
```

Which is wrong since `this_` would be the pakage. So both restriction work on the same field but non on the pole.length field.

Is there a solution to `select all Pakages which have a length >= the user input OR which contain a Pole which has a length the user input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create alias for joined table and use it in restrictions. Something like this:

```
Pole poleJoin = null; // <- created alias
session.QueryOver<Pakage>()
        .JoinAlias(x => x.Poles, () => poleJoin, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
        .Where(x => x.Length >= seLengthFrom.Value) || poleJoin.Length >= seLengthFrom.Value))
        .Select(Projections.RootEntity())
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
        .List();
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. I also improved the load time by applying the filtering in a subquery, which returns the pakageIds, so I do not nead the `DistinctRootEntity` transformer and the query is much faster.

Comment: I think subquery is much faster due to presence of Pole fields in select statement. It can also be avoided by adding `.Select(Projections.RootEntity())` (added to answer)